# How to count sales per day per salesperson

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how many sales a salesperson closes per day.

I tried the query shown below. It returned the amount of sales per salesman per day per saleid. That last part is the problem because i want to group the sales per salesperson per day. The group by clause won't allow that though. It's logical because the query matches the salesperson name per saleid. Therefore saleid must be included in the group by clause because if it is not then the query cannot know which entry to return regarding the salesperson - saleid pair. At least that's what i think happens.

This is the query.

```
select
(select users.firstname + ' ' + users.lastname from users where id =
    (select value from entdatadetails left join entfields on entfield_id = entfields.id where fld_code = 'order_salesman' and entdata_id = entdatas.id)) as salesman,
count(entdatas.id) as no_of_orders,
cast(entdatas.created_at as date),
entdatas.id
from
entdatadetails
left join entdatas
on entdatas.id = entdata_id
left join entfields
on entfields.id = entfield_id
where fld_code = 'order_salesman'
and isActive = 1
and cast(entdatas.created_at as date) < cast(getdate() as date)
group by cast(entdatas.created_at as date), entdatas.id
order by cast(entdatas.created_at as date) asc
```

And this is an example of the table it generates.

[Generated table (cropped due to sensitive data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nQ2w.png)

The salespeople names are not shown but by their endings one can figure out how many sales there are.
What I essentially need is for the entdatas.id to be gone from the group by but it is not allowed by the way the query is structured.

Comment: + in mysql is an arithmetic operator , and getdate(0 is not a mysql function is this a MSSQL/sql-server question rather than mysql?

Comment: MSSQL my bad editing now

Comment: BTW you can't start a query with an opening bracket..

Answer (score 0):

Use group_concat to group all entry ids with comma separated and group by user id i.e, the sales person id (entdatas.salesperson_id). pls refer to modified query

```
 SELECT
  (SELECT users.firstname + ' ' + users.lastname
   FROM users
   WHERE id =
       (SELECT value
        FROM entdatadetails
        LEFT JOIN entfields ON entfield_id = entfields.id
        WHERE fld_code = 'order_salesman'
          AND entdata_id = entdatas.id)) AS salesman,
       count(entdatas.id) AS no_of_orders,
       cast(entdatas.created_at AS date),
       entdatas.id
FROM entdatadetails
LEFT JOIN entdatas ON entdatas.id = entdata_id
LEFT JOIN entfields ON entfields.id = entfield_id
WHERE fld_code = 'order_salesman'
  AND isActive = 1
  AND cast(entdatas.created_at AS date) < cast(getdate() AS date)
GROUP BY cast(entdatas.created_at AS date),
         entfield_id
ORDER BY cast(entdatas.created_at AS date) ASC
```

Comment: No it did not work. I'm on mssql therefore the corresponding function is string_agg. The salesperson_id you suggest is the where id = ... subquery. It cannot be used in a group by clause.

Comment: Refer to the above modified query